# How can I resolve the 'BertForSequenceClassification requires the PyTorch library' error while using BERT model?

Tags: pytorch, nlp, torch, bert-language-model

**Facing this issue while using BERT model **
**Any suggestions for resolving this error. **

> Import Error:  BertForSequenceClassification requires the PyTorch
> library, but it was not found in your environment. However, we were
> able to find a TensorFlow installation. TensorFlow classes begin. with
> "TF" but are otherwise identically named to our PyTorch classes. This
> means that the TF equivalent of the class you tried to import would be
> "TFBertForSequenceClassification". If you want to use TensorFlow,
> please use TF classes instead!
>
> If you really do want to use PyTorch please go to
> https://pytorch.org/get-started/locally/ and follow the instructions
> that. match your environment.

I am trying to use the BERT model for autocorrection. It requires the torch model. While executing the below line of code:  **model = BertForSequenceClassification.from_pretrained('bert-base-uncased')**  I am facing the issue. Tried resolving it but couldn't find solution to this.

Comment: Can you give more details about your environment? If you are using a Jupyter notebook kernel, and you have already installed PyTorch, try restarting it.